# In how many ways we can score at least 6 in 6 balls/deliveries?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked in an interview last year:

Q. In how many ways you can score at least 6 in 6 balls/deliveries?

Rules: There is a possibility of scoring 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or maximum 6 from one ball/delivery. Each ball is valid (no extra ball). When total score is 6 or more, game over (no need to score even if there are balls left).

For example:
Possible ways: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4], [6], [1, 1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6] and so many.

[0, 3, 4, 5] is not a proper way as score 6 achieved at 3rd ball.

I have to write a code that will find the number of different ways that it can be done.

What I tried:

I tried to solve this problem using "Climbing Staircase Problem" where someone can climb 1, 2 or 3 strairs at a time. How many ways to reach the n'th stairs.

Here is the recursive solution for the staircase problem:

```
   public static long possibleWaysRec(int n)
   {
      if (n == 0 || n == 1)
         return 1L;

      if (n == 2)
         return 2L;

      return (possibleWaysRec(n - 1) + possibleWaysRec(n - 2) + possibleWaysRec(n - 3));
   }
```

Now, the difference between these two problem is that, in The Staircase Problem, total stairs are known (here it is the target score) and there is no bound on required steps but in my problem I've 6 opportunities. Another difference is that score may not got increased after each delivary (when 0 scored) but in staircase position must change with each step (regardless of 1, 2 or 3).

I need to modify this it in someway to keep track of how many balls I used to reach the target score. 
Or any other approach to solve this problem, so that I can find the all possible combinations if I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem recursively, similar to your "Climbing Staircase Problem" with a List that keeps track of the used balls so far, so that it doesn't exceed than the available/permitted balls.

You can get all possible ways as well (just display the list values.)

```
public class WaysToScore 
{
    static long count=0;

    public static void waysToDo(int score, int target, List<Short> waySoFar)
    {
        if(waySoFar.size() > 6) return;  //  total balls

        if(score >= target && score < target+6)
        {
            count++;
            return;
        }

        for(short i=0; i<=6; i++)   //  scoring options per ball
        {
            waySoFar.add(i);

            waysToDo(score+i, target, waySoFar);

            waySoFar.remove(waySoFar.size()-1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int target = 6 ;  //  total scores.

        waysToDo(0, target, new ArrayList<Short>());

        System.out.println("Total ways: "+count);
    }
}
```

Output: `Total ways: 2311`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand the problem, which maybe I don't, then I would do it with six nested loops:

```
 count_the_ways = 0;
 for a from 0 to 6:
   for b from 0 to 6:
     [...]
       if (a+b+c+d+e+f >= 6) count_the_ways++
```

Answer this way is `116,275.`

If you want to say that "you should stop throwing balls as soon as the total equals or exceeds six" that's easily done with an `if` statement e.g.

```
 if (a+b) < 6:
   for c from 0 to 6 ...
```

The description is not quite clear when it says "6 *or more."*  Maybe we want:

```
   for c from 0 to 6-(a+b) ...
```

and so on.

A recursive variation is of course possible but in this case relatively unnecessary.

Comment: By saying 6 or more means, 4+4 or 4+6 or some combination that is just 6 or over but without the last score (ball) it will be less than 6. Now 4+2+3+0+0+0 is not a part of solution. I think your code will generate all.