# How can I convert this Recursive function to Iterative/Dynamic_Programming?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

This recursive program solves the problem of "In how many ways you can score at least 6 in 6 balls/deliveries?"

The details can be found here, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117310/in-how-many-ways-we-can-score-at-least-6-in-6-balls-deliveries/60180211#60180211)

This program works fine. Recently I've generalized the program for any amount of Runs with any amount of Balls/deliveries.

My program works fine but it is very slow even for some moderate inputs like Runs = 20, Balls = 10.

I am trying to avoid **recursion** with `Dynamic Programming approach (DP)` but couldn't construct the Table correctly since the total runs will not be exactly 20 (in this case) it could be 20 to 25 (considering a 6 when the score was at 19) and balls could be much less than 10 (considering 6, 6, 6, 6 or some other high scoring options).

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my modified code,

```
static long count=0;
static int myTarget=20, balls = 10;

public static void waysToDo(int score, int target, List<Short> waySoFar)
{
    if(waySoFar.size() > balls ) return;  //  total balls

    if(score >= target)
    {
        count++;
        return;
    }

    for(short i=0; i<=6; i++)   //  scoring options per ball
    {
        waySoFar.add(i);

        waysToDo(score+i, target, waySoFar);

        waySoFar.remove(waySoFar.size()-1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{        
    waysToDo(0, target, new ArrayList<Short>());
    System.out.println("Total ways: "+count);
}
```

Comment: Since I'm looking for a generalization, scoring is fixed (from 0 to 6) but balls are not fixed at 6, it could be any number, and there is another factor that I had plan to consider later (when batter got out and we have a limited batters).

Answer (score 0):

Let start from base case.

What happens if we have only one iteration? Every outcome can be achieved only one way, so:

```
result[0][0] = 1
result[0][1] = 1
result[0][2] = 1
result[0][3] = 1
result[0][4] = 1
result[0][5] = 1
```

*First index is iteration, second is score. Value is number of possible way to achieve it*

On second iteration:

- `0` can be achieved only 1 way.
- `1` can be achieved two ways: we can score `1` if previous score was `0` or we can score `0` if previous score was `1`
- `2` can be achieved 3 ways: `2` + `0`, `1` + `1` and `0` + `2`
- and so on.

If we generalize we have on step `n` result be:

- `0` only 1 way
- `1` numbers of way to get `1` on step `n-1` plus number of ways to get `0`  on step `n-1`
- `2`: `result[n-1][0] + result[n-1][1] + result[n-1][2]`
- `m`: sum `result[n-1][x]` where `x` is between 0 and m
- `6`: you don't need to take into account previous value for 6. So sum `result[n-1][x]` where `x` is between 0 and 5.

So you end up with something like

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
    result[0][i]=1;
}

for(int n=1; n<=maxStep; n++){
   for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
       result[n][i]=0;
       for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
           result[n][i] += result[n-1][j];
       }
   }
}
System.out.println(result[maxStep][5]);
```

*If you noticed we only need current and previous, so there is opportunity for memory optimization.*

Comment: @user16320675 Yes. That is misspelling.